# Conditional color: why doesn't this MWE work?

Tags: color, conditionals

I want to have a global control on colors.

This MWE does not work... What is the issue?

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\def\versionNB
%\def\versionColor

% -----------------------------------%
%
\def\colorNB{black}
\def\colorColor{blue}
%
\def\myColor
{%
\ifdefined\versionNB%
\colorNB%
\else%
\colorColor%
\fi}
% -----------------------------------%

\color{\myColor}

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use \def unless you really know what you are doing. And your `\def\versionNB` is missing the argument.

Comment: `\def\versionNB
%\def\versionColor

% -----------------------------------%
%
\def\colorNB{black}` defines `versionNB` so that it must be followed by  `\par\def\colorNB` and expands to `black`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `\show` to your example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\def\versionNB
%\def\versionColor

% -----------------------------------%
%
\def\colorNB{black}

\show\versionNB

\def\colorColor{blue}
%
\def\myColor
{%
\ifdefined\versionNB%
\colorNB%
\else%
\colorColor%
\fi}
% -----------------------------------%

\color{\myColor}

test

\end{document}
```

produces

```
> \versionNB=macro:
\par \def \colorNB ->black.
l.14 \show\versionNB
                    
?
```

so `\versionNB` is defined such that

```
\versionNB\par \def \colorNB
```

would expand to `black` and any other use of `\versionNB` is an error.

`\colorNB` is not defined, `\def \colorNB` are unevaluated tokens in the parameter text of `\versionNB` so later you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\myColor ->\ifdefined \versionNB \colorNB 
                                          \else \colorColor \fi 
l.27 \color{\myColor}
                     
?
```

Pesumably you intended

```
\def\versionNB{}
```